# Docker environment variable empty in Sitecore patch file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, sitecore, unicorn

Following this document:
https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/101/developer-tools/sync-items-with-a-running-container.html,
I tried to set the sourceFolder variable in a Sitecore patch config file as follows:

```
<sc.variable name="sourceFolder" value="$(env:ITEM_SYNC_LOCATION)" />
```

and I deployed the Sitecore 10.1 solution (with the above configuration) to the CM Docker container based on Windows Server image.
The sourceFolder variable is always empty,
even though the ITEM_SYNC_LOCATION environment variable exists in the container and has the value specified in the docker-compose.yml file:

```
  cm:
    [...]
    environment:
      ITEM_SYNC_LOCATION: c:\items-mounted
    volumes:
      - ${LOCAL_ITEM_PATH}:c:\items-mounted
```

I have performed several reboots of the CM container but the problem  persists.
What could I have missed?

Comment: Hi Massimo, Might seem obvious but how are you confirming the variable? If you jump into the container and run SET in CMD, does the envionment variable show? If you login and navigate to [instance]/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx and search for the variable, does it show your patch being applied?

Comment: Hi Dean, the variable is set and displayed correctly and, despite this, if I try to check it via showconfig, the variable is always empty in the patch applied.